# import .Net Framework 4.5 library in .Net Core MVC App

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to add .NET Framework 4.5 my own dll to .NET Core Project but I can't. I also try to change something in project.json file but without result. I also try to make custom local Nuget source but it don't work for me.
can anyone know right explanation how can I do this ?

See screen below:
[image: import .net framework 4.5 dll to .NET core]

Comment: The message doesn't refere to 4.5 at all. .NET Core and .NET Framework 4.5 are different *target platforms*. You can't "import" one into the other as if they were libraries. What it says is that you can't add a reference to any assembly except those packaged with .NET Core itself. You'll have to package your library in a Nuget package then add the package to your project

Comment: Is Dea.Html another .NET Core library ?

Answer (score 1):

## Update

As of .NET Core 2.0, this can now be done: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/#reference-net-framework-libraries-from-net-standard

---

You can't reference a .NET Framework 4.5 assembly in a .NET Core project, only other .NET Core assemblies.

If you want to use ASP.NET Core 1 and still be able to reference .NET "Full" assemblies, you have to create a ASP.NET application that targets the .NET Framework instead of .NET Core. You can do this by going to Create a new Project -> Visual C# -> Web -> ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework).

You can also change your project.json file to reference the full .NET Framework, like this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
}
```

Also, if you're willing to write platform-specific code and use pre-compiler directives, you can target multiple frameworks on a single app.

To do that, simply add `net461` to your existing app, alongside `netcoreapp1.0`. Note, though, that you'll have to specify your dependencies for each framework. So your project.json file will look something like this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "type":"platform", "version": "1.0.0" }
        },
        "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
    "net461": { 
        "dependencies": {"MyNet45Assembly"}
    }
}
```

And then on your code you'll have to use pre-compiler directives to detect under which platform your app is running. For example:

```
#if NET461
using MyNet45Assembly.Types;
#endif

// ...

#if NET461
var v = new MyNet45AssemblyType();
#endif
```

Comment: The message refers to a different problem entirely, how to add another .NET Core assembly reference to a project. Which can't be done right now, without creating a NuGet package